# Python: Group List by Set of Keys

Tags: python, list, key, set, tuples

I have an input list of tuples whose entries are:

```
input_1 = [('v1',['f1','f2','f3']),('v2',['f1','f2','f4']),('v3',['f1','f2','f4'])]
                  ^^^^^^^^^               ^^^^^^^^^               ^^^^^^^^^
```

I want to know if there is a way to get a list of tuples containing "groups" like the following:

```
output_1 = [(['f1','f2'],['v1','v2','v3']) , (['f3'],['v1']), (['f4'],['v2','v3'])]
```

In case that's not enough information, other inputs/outputs might be:

```
input_2 = [('v1',['f1']),('v2',['f2','f3']),('v3',['f4'])]

output_2 = [(['f1'],['v1']) , (['f2','f3'],['v2']), (['f4'],['v3'])]
```

or

```
input_3 = [('v1',['f1','f2']),('v2',['f1','f2']),('v3',['f3']),('v4',['f1','f2'])]
                  ^^^^^^^^^          ^^^^^^^^^                        ^^^^^^^^^

output_3 = [(['f1','f2'],['v1','v2','v4']) , (['f3'],['v3'])]
```

I think there may be a way to achieve this with implementing the dictionary, but I'm new with Python and I can't figure out how to do this from the examples that I've seen:

[Grouping integers by set membership in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040919/grouping-integers-by-set-membership-in-python)

[Make sure all dicts in a list have the same keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10482439/make-sure-all-dicts-in-a-list-have-the-same-keys)

I think I could manage to do this, inefficiently, with a bunch of for loops, but is there a pythonic or clean alternative? Sorry if this question was not well posed but thank you for any input.

Comment: Tricky. What do you expect as output from `[('v1'),['f1','f2','f3']),('v2',['f2','f3','f4'])]` or from `[('v1'),['f1','f2','f3']),('v2',['f1','f4','f3'])]`? What about `[('v1'),['f1','f2','f3']),('v2',['f2','f3','f4']),('v3',['f1','f2','f4'])]`?

Comment: @TimPietzcker, I would expect: [('f1',['v1']),(['f2','f3'],['v1','v2']),(['f4'],['v2'])] for the first one...

Comment: For the second one, assuming you meant: [(['v1'],['f1','f2','f3']),('v2',['f1','f4','f3'])], The output should be: [(['f1','f3'],['v1','v2']),(['f2'],['v1']),(['f4'],['v2'])]. Sorry if I'm inconsistent with whether the first element in the output tuple is a list or just a string, it can always be a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could iterate through both levels then rebuild the input flipping the levels around; it gets you most of the way.  The major issue is how would you group the `v`'s  that share `f`'s...there are different permutations that could give you the same result as Tim suggests.

[image: Different output grouping permutations...which is more valid?]

Anyways: this is a start.

```
from collections import defaultdict

input_1 = [('v1',['f1','f2','f3']),
           ('v2',['f1','f2','f4']),
           ('v3',['f1','f2','f4'])]
input_2 = [('v1',['f1']),
           ('v2',['f2','f3']),
           ('v3',['f4'])]
input_3 = [('v1',['f1','f2']),
           ('v2',['f1','f2']),
           ('v3',['f3']),
           ('v4',['f1','f2'])]

def group(inp):
    out = defaultdict(list)
    for group in inp:
        key = group[0]
        for entry in group[1]:
            out[entry].append(key)
    return dict(out)
```

Outputs would look like:

```
print group(input_1)
# {'f1': ['v1', 'v2', 'v3'], 
#  'f2': ['v1', 'v2', 'v3'], 
#  'f3': ['v1'], 
#  'f4': ['v2', 'v3']}
print group(input_2)
# {'f1': ['v1'], 
#  'f2': ['v2'], 
#  'f3': ['v2'], 
#  'f4': ['v3']}
print group(input_3)
# {'f1': ['v1', 'v2', 'v4'], 
#  'f2': ['v1', 'v2', 'v4'], 
#  'f3': ['v3']}
```

Comment: +1, you could then do a second loop to find all the keys that have identical values and join them together.

Comment: That looks great! The rest should be easy enough, though I do wonder if there is a more concise way, only because I've been pretty impressed with Python's list comprehensions. Then again, I'm not familiar yet with dictionaries. Either way I think this will do, thank you!

Comment: @TimPietzcker I think as you were alluding to, that can be more difficult than it would seem (see image)

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer! And how did you make that graphic? I think I understand the distinction. I believe for my application, any of the possible outputs will work. The point, for my application, is that when the list of v's is large and are contained in many groups of f's, the number of unique tuples becomes small. Thanks @Nick T!

Comment: @Charlie Quick and dirty in Excel (was going to draw it in MSPaint but my tablet is being a jerk)

Comment: Hah, cool. I thought it was something fancy I didn't know about